# Why is Aorta sometimes called Compression chamber?

Tags: physiology, cardiology

I find this statement that Aorta is called Compression Chamber in my study materials.

Aorta can

- it keeps blood flowing
- it can accumulate potential energy for bumping and compression

**However, why aorta is called chamber and particularly compression chamber?**
I heard this term today first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The aorta is a compression chamber because it is an important drive for diastolic perfusion. To keep the blood flowing constantly, and not only during systole (as would be the case with a rigid aorta), the **high elasticity of the aortic walls allows it to dilate as a consequence of the high systolic pressure**. This **allows the aorta to accumulate blood** in its proximal part, which is then **propelled by the passive elastic contraction of the aorta during diastole**.